# How to create two partial views in the same page with one updating the other

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to do this and end up getting different errors every time.

View Model

```
public class BookVm
{
public int BookId {get; set;}
public string BookName {get ; set;}
public string Author {get; set;}
}
```

This is what I want. I want to have two partial views in the same page where one view allow user to add books and the other shows the list of all books. When user adds a book , the list of the books should update. How do I do this?  Please add code samples

Note: I only want to use partial views, not Ajax.

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: If you don't want ajax, then submit the form, add the new book and redirect to the same method. Using partial views has got nothing to do with your issue.